# Capture specific key combination while in GUI

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to capture when an user presses Ctrl+Enter on his keyboard while being in my application:

```
class UI(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(UI, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'w':
            print("yes")
            return False
        return True


class UIApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return UI()

UIApp().run()
```

I realize that this code would capture `w`, but it doesn't even do this. Or at least yes isn't printed to console. My UI:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<UI>:
    title: 'InputDialog'
    auto_dismiss: False

    RelativeLayout:
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `modifiers[0] == 'ctrl'` and `keycode[0] == 13` or `text is None`:

```
def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
    if len(modifiers) > 0 and modifiers[0] == 'ctrl' and keycode[0] == 13:     
        # ctrl + enter pressed
        print("\nThe key", keycode, "have been pressed")
        print(" - text is %r" % text)
        print(" - modifiers are %r" % modifiers)
```